# how to append fields values in python list and ignore None value

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

i need To calculate average of some fields values and ignore none values from being calculated thats what i could done

```
@api.multi
def update_bar(self):
    list=[self.item.pro, self.drc.pro, self.dsc.pro, self.org.pro, 
          self.car.pro, self.model.pro, self.year.pro]
    for rec in list:
        if rec:
            self.new_list = list.append(rec)
    print(self.new_list)
    pass
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Your solution should work well.

Comment: it's take to long time and freez pc
i test it from a button in odoo form view 
i have more than 5000 product

Comment: Please update your question with more information. For example in everything i can read by now, i don't see any relation to Odoo, except for that decorator, which means nothing with a proper context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it using list comprehension

```
def average_or_none(ls):
    temp = [x for x in ls if x is not None]

    if temp:
        return sum(temp) / len(temp)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: i'am sorry dear but how can use your methode in my code 
i'am new at python

Comment: Thanks dear it worked Well and remove all zeros 
but may be i couldn't define my problem as well as 
all i need not just Remove value =  None 
values above is one2many fields i need if i didn't chose any record to the field never calculated to the list 
but if i get record to to the field add it to the list even if it 0

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `None` values from the list and do your regular summation/average calculation further. Let's filter out the `None`'s like below-

```
list=[self.item.pro, self.drc.pro, self.dsc.pro, self.org.pro, 
          self.car.pro, self.model.pro, self.year.pro]
list_without_none = [x for x in list if x is not None]
```

***To calculate average***, Say you've values like below.

```
# Python program to get average of a list 
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 

# Driver Code 
list_without_none = [15, 9, 55, 41, 35, 20, 62, 49] 
average = Average(list_without_none) 
print(average)
```

**SEE MORE** [DEMO's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-average-list-python/)

Comment: Thanks dear it worked Well and remove all zeros but may be i couldn't define my problem as well as all i need not just Remove value = None values above is one2many fields i need if i didn't chose any record to the field never calculated to the list but if i get record to to the field add it to the list even if it 0

Answer (score 0):

You can always use filter function. Example below. As a result you will get your first list but with Nones filtred out.

```
new_list = filter(lambda x: x is not None, list)
mean = sum(new_list)/len(new_list)
```